# Bash, selecting text surrounded by specific matches

Tags: bash, sed, grep

What I need to do is print out the text which starts after the particular match and ends before another match.

Let's say I have a big output and I only need to print the text which starts after line '$$$$$$$$$$' and ends before line '((((((((('. Oh and the file might end without the '(((((((((' line, in which case I would still need that text after '$$$$$$$$$$' till the end of the output.
How would I do that?

Comment: an example would be better. Does the match contain new line chars?

Comment: Ignore much of the discussion just find the final snippet in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk) question and use that it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -e '/\$\{10\}/,/(\{9\}/!d' inputfile
```

To exclude the boundary lines, you have to do some programming:

```
sed -ne '/\$\{10\}/ {n;b c}; d;:c {/(\{9\}/ {d};p;n;b c}' inputfile
```

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for! I'am curious tho, what does that "!d" at the end stand for?

Comment: `d` is for "delete", `!` means `otherwise`. So, print the lines in the address range, otherwise delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '/START/{f=1;next} /END/{f=0} f' file
```

You can set `start` `stop` to what you like.

cat file

```
test
$$$$$$$$$$
more
data
(((((((((
stop
```

```
awk '/\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$/{f=1;next} /\(\(\(\(\(\(\(\(\(/{f=0} f' t
more
data
```

Since `$` and `(` is special characters, you need to escape them.