# Sed not reading multiline input?

Tags: regex, sed, multiline

I have some text as below:

```
path => ["/home/Desktop/**/auditd.log",
        "/home/Desktop/**/rsyslog*.log",
        "/home/Desktop/**/snmpd.log",
        "/home/Desktop/**/kernel.log",
        "/home//Desktop/**/ntpd.log",
        "/home/Desktop/**/mysql*.log",
        "/home/Desktop/**/sshd.log",
        "/hme/Desktop/**/su.log",
        "/home/Desktop/**/run-parts(.log"
    ]
```

I want to extract the values inside `[` `]`, so I am doing:

```
sed -n 's/.*\[\(.*\)\]/\1/p'
```

Sed is not returning anything.

If I do `sed -n 's/.*\[\(.*\)log/\1/p` it's returning properly the string between `[` and `log`.

```
"/home/Desktop/**/auditd.",
```

So it's able to search within the line.

How to make this work??

EDIT:

I created a file with content:

```
path => [asd,masd,dasd
sdalsd,ad
asdlmas;ldasd
]
```

When I do `grep -o '\[.*\]'` it does not work but `grep -o '\[.*'` this returns the 1st line `[asd,masd,dasd`. So it's working for single line not for multiple lines.

Comment: sed is line-oriented. Your first pattern doesn't match on any of the lines in your input.

Comment: So how to extract multiple lines if one has to ?? Grep also returns searches on same line

Comment: If you need to match contents between lines use something like `awk` or some tool that can actually understand the input format. The last bit of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk) shows you a very handy awk pattern for range-of-line processing.

Comment: I did use awk: `awk '/\[/,/\]/'` but it's returning an output which is same as input as it's including `path =>` in the output

Comment: This file is the output of what ? Seems a Data Structure

Comment: It's the output of an `awk` which I did on my file and now I was applying `sed` on the output of awk. Something like this: `awk '/path => \[/,/\]/' abc.conf|sed -n 's/.*\[\(.*\)\]/\1/p'`

Comment: Yes, a simple range pattern isn't enough you need to then actually transform the lines the way you want. Same as for sed/grep. And as the linked question indicated a range pattern is generally not what you want, the last bit is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ grep -o '".*",?' file
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
"/home/Desktop/**/auditd.log",
"/home/Desktop/**/rsyslog*.log",
"/home/Desktop/**/snmpd.log",
"/home/Desktop/**/kernel.log",
"/home//Desktop/**/ntpd.log",
"/home/Desktop/**/mysql*.log",
"/home/Desktop/**/sshd.log",
"/hme/Desktop/**/su.log",
"/home/Desktop/**/run-parts(.log"
```

- `-o` for grep print only the matching part
- `"` is a literal double quote
- `.*` is anything
- `"` si the closing double quote
- `,` is a literal double quote
- `?` mean o or 1 occurrence

Comment: Can you please explain this?

Comment: Ok. I got it, it's capturing only `""` `,` . But in some other case when the input is different, how to capture multiple lines ??

Comment: it's capturing not only "" but also what's inside. Next time, you have to adapt the regex.

Comment: I meant what if no particular pattern is there in the input. Like in the above case ".*,?"  was a pattern and we greped that. What if we had to capture text b/w [ ] but data inside [ ] was random. In that case doing a .* does not work for multiple lines. So how to achieve that?

Comment: I created a file with content:                                   `path => [asd,masd,dasd
sdalsd,ad
asdlmas;ldasd
]
` When I do `grep -o '\[.*\]'` it does not work but `grep -o '\[.*'` this returns the 1st line `[asd,masd,dasd`. So it's working for single line not for multiple lines.

Comment: I edited my question plz check there. In comments the file input formatting could not be done properly.

Comment: grep is line oriented.

Comment: Yes. So can we achieve to extract multiple lines. I know sed is line oriented too and awk returns an output with whole line like path => will also be there. So is there a way?

Comment: In your answer there must be a `\?` rather than just `?`, something like this: `grep -o '".*",\?' file`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was a bit too slow, but I think the question of how to apply sed substitutions to a whole file as a block rather than on a line-by-line basis merits a general answer, so I'll leave one here.

In your specific case, you could use this pattern:

```
sed -n 'H; $ { x; s/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/; p; }' foo.txt
```

The general trick is

```
sed -n 'H; $ { x; s/pattern/replacement/flags; p; }' file
```

What this means is: Every line that comes in is appended to the hold buffer (with the `H` command), and at the end of the file (`$`), when the whole file is in the hold buffer, the stuff between the brackets is executed. In that block, the hold buffer is swapped with the pattern space (`x`), then the substitution is done, and what remains in the pattern space is printed (`p`).

EDIT: One caveat of this simple form is that it doesn't work properly if your pattern wants to match the beginning of the file; for reasons the hold buffer is not entirely empty when sed is first called (it contains an empty line). If this is important, the slightly more complicated form

```
sed -n '1 h; 1 !H; $ { x; s/pattern/replacement/flags; p; }' file
```

fixes it. This will use `h` instead of `H` for the first line, which overwrites the hold buffer with the pattern space rather than appending the pattern space to the hold buffer.

Comment: `s/.*\[` could failed because the first `.*` take the loingest possible pattern, so it take until last `[` before the last `]` that could be in the middle of the block. I propose to use `^[^[]*\[` instead

Comment: Depending on what exactly OP wants to match if there are several pairs of brackets in the file, that is a valid point, yes. I only copied OP's regex.

Comment: This is the `"/home/Desktop/**/run-parts(.log"` line that make me write the remark suspecting other special char like `[` possible in string

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk` by replacing `.*[` or `]` or white spaces with nothing:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/.*\[|\]| /, ""); print}' filename

"/home/Desktop/**/auditd.log",
"/home/Desktop/**/rsyslog*.log",
"/home/Desktop/**/snmpd.log",
"/home/Desktop/**/kernel.log",
"/home//Desktop/**/ntpd.log",
"/home/Desktop/**/mysql*.log",
"/home/Desktop/**/sshd.log",
"/hme/Desktop/**/su.log",
"/home/Desktop/**/run-parts(.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

from your sample, it could also be (treat only first and last line)

```
sed '1s/^[^[]*\[//;$d' YourFile
```