# Bash, grep between two lines with specified string in a file having multiple set of such lines

Tags: linux, bash

Example:

```
a43
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
kfo
a43
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
kfo
a43
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
kfo
```

i need to find all lines between first occurence of test1 and test2. Below grep command does not work for this :

```
grep -A100000 test1 file.txt | grep -B100000 test2 > new.txt
```

can you please let me know if any modifications are needed to do the same?

Comment: This question (and discussion) are likely helpful here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk

Answer (score 0):

This awk should do the job:

```
awk '/test1/{p=1} p; /test2/{exit}' file
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
```