# Split file by extracting lines between two keywords

Tags: bash, awk, csplit

I have a file with the following lines:

```
string
string
string
MODEL 1
.
.
.
TER
string 
string
string
MODEL 2
.
.
.
TER
```

where there are 5000 such `MODEL`s. I want to split this file such that each section beginning `MODEL X` and ending `TER` (shown with dots) is saved to its own file, and everything else is discarded. How can I do this? Possibly with `awk` or `split`?

I have checked a couple of other similar questions, but failed to apply the answers to my case.

Also note that I use Mac OS X.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23934486/258523 for a discussion of ways to do this in `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk for this:

```
awk '/^MODEL/{file="model" $2} file{print > file} /^TER/{close(file); file=""}' file
```

**How it works:**

```
/^MODEL/               # match lines starting with MODEL
file="model" $2        # make variable file as model + model_no from column 2
file{...}              # execute of file variable is set
{print>file}           # print each record to file
/^TER/                 # match lines starting with TER
{close(file); file=""} # close file and reset file to ""
```

Then verify as:

```
cat model1
MODEL 1
.
.
.
TER

cat model2
MODEL 2
.
.
.
TER
```

Comment: It works until the 18th file, at which point it terminates with the error: `awk: model18 makes too many open files`. It also prints the `string` lines after `TER`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works perfectly now. Could you please explain the command a little for me to understand how it works?

Comment: I've added some description in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works even with `dash`:

```
go=false text= model_ID=
while IFS= read line; do
    if   [ "`printf "$line" | grep '^MODEL'`" ]; then
        model_ID="`printf "$line" | sed -e 's/^MODEL //'`"
        go=true
    elif [ "`printf "$line" | grep '^TER'`" ];   then
        printf "$text" > "MODEL_$model_ID"
        text=""
        model_ID=""
        go=false
    else
        $go && text="$text$line\n"
    fi
done
```