# How to extract lines after founding specific string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

My example text is,

```
AA BB  CC
DDD
process.get('name1')
process.get('name2')
process.get('name3')
process.get('name4')
process.get('name5')
process.get('name6')
EEE
FFF
...
```

I want to search the string "*process.get('name1')*" first, if found then extract the lines from "*process.get('name1')*" to  "*process.get('name6')*".

How do I extract the lines using sed?

Answer (score 3):

This should work and... it uses sed as per OP request:

```
$ sed -n "/^process\.get('name1')$/,/^process\.get('name6')$/p" file
```

Answer (score 2):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, for anything more interesting you should be using awk:

```
$ awk -v beg="process.get('name1')" -v end="process.get('name6')" \
    'index($0,beg){f=1} f; index($0,end){f=0}' file
process.get('name1')
process.get('name2')
process.get('name3')
process.get('name4')
process.get('name5')
process.get('name6')
```

Note that you could use a range in awk, just like you are forced to in sed:

```
awk -v beg="process.get('name1')" -v end="process.get('name6')" \
        'index($0,beg),index($0,end)' file
```

and you could use regexps after escaping metachars in awk, just like you are forced to in sed:

```
awk "/process\.get\('name1'\)/,/process\.get\('name6'\)/" file
```

but the first awk version above using strings instead of regexps and a flag variable is simpler (in as much as you don't have to figure out which chars are/aren't RE metacharacters), more robust and more easily extensible in future.

It's important to note that sed CANNOT operate on strings, just regexps, so when you say "I want to search for a string" you should stop trying to force sed to behave as if it can do that.

Imagine your search strings are passed in to a script as positional parameters `$1` and `$2`. With awk you'd just init the awk variables from them in the expected way:

```
awk -v beg="$1" -v end="$2" 'index($0,beg){f=1} f; index($0,end){f=0}' file
```

whereas with sed you'd have to do something like:

```
beg=$(sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<< "$1")
end=$(sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<< "$2")
sed -n "/^${beg}$/,/^${end}$/p" file
```

to deactivate any metacharacters present. See [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001) for details on escaping RE metachars for sed.

Finally - as mentioned above you COULD use a range expression with strings in awk:

```
awk -v beg="$1" -v end="$2" 'index($0,beg),index($0,end)' file
```

but I personally have never found that useful, there's always some slight requirements change comes along to make me wish I'd started out using a flag. See [Is a /start/,/end/ range expression ever useful in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23934486/1745001) for details on that

Comment: why `index `instead of `$0~` ?

Comment: because index() operates on strings instead of regexps so you don't need to escape RE metacharacters to use it so it's simpler and far more robust for a case like this where the OP clearly wants to just search for literal strings.

Comment: I added more of an explanation to help clarify.

Comment: @Ed Morton Wouldn't this do? `awk '/name1/ {f=1}; f; /name6/ {f=0}' file`

Comment: @user2138595 No. In addition to what I said above about the OP just wanting to use strings, not regexps, imagine what your example would do if `name123` or `surname654` existed in the file.