# Error "awk: too many output files 10" when splitting SSL certificates

Tags: bash, unix, ssl, awk, openssl

I'm trying to split a file that contains multiple SSL certificates with AWK but is showing an error message:
awk: too many output files 10

Command that I'm using is the following:

```
cat ${SSL_CERTIFICATES_PATH} | awk '/BEGIN/ { i++; } /BEGIN/, /END/ { print > i ".extracted.crt" }'
```

Error Message:

```
awk: too many output files 10
record number 735
```

Do you know how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to close the files each time variable i's value gets increases by 1, so try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/BEGIN/ {close(i".extracted.crt");i++} /BEGIN/, /END/ { print > i".extracted.crt" }' ${SSL_CERTIFICATES_PATH}
```

**EDIT:** Xavier, I have checked with a friend who has SUN 5 with him and following worked well without any error. You could put variable as per your need.

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk '/BEGIN/ {close(i".extracted.crt");i++} /BEGIN/, /END/ { print > i".extracted.crt" }' *.crt
```

Comment: I just tried with the command that you gave me and is still displaying the same message...

Comment: try the edited one now and let me know if this helps you. I am sure it should work, because I changed the places of close and I variable now.

Comment: An unparenthesized expression on the right side of output redirection is undefined behavior, so your awk may be interpreting `print > i".extracted.crt"` as `(print > i)".extracted.crt"` (whatever that means!) instead of the presumably intended `print > (i".extracted.crt")`. Always parenthesize any expression on the right side of output redirection.

Comment: Also I did with parentheses and still getting the same message `awk: too many output files 10`

Comment: Have you stopped using old, broken awk? If so which awk are you now using?

Comment: I'm trying to get the version of the AWK but is not working using `awk --version`

Comment: @JavierSalas: Are you using csh or any old shell, could you please mention that also in your post.

Comment: is KSH using SunOS 5.10.

Comment: @JavierSalas: I just tested my edited code in which I only made difference of changing awk to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk and it worked well, let me know if this helps you now?

Comment: Yesssss BINGO, glad that it helped you :), enjoy learning in here, keep posting and keep sharing.

Comment: @JavierSalas I told you to change to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk 3 hours earlier....

Comment: @EdMorton sorry, I didn't try your solution due I didn't see it, but I really appreciate all your answers and support! Thank you!

Comment: It wasn't a solution it's the second comment under [Akshay's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45285686/1745001). You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You have to `close()` file,

<s>`awk '/BEGIN/ {f=i++".extracted.crt"}/BEGIN/,/END/{print > f;if(/END/)close(f)}'`</s>

The Best solution as suggested by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton), one should not use range expressions, for more details [Read Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk)

```
awk '/BEGIN/{f=(++i)".extracted.crt"} f{print>f} /END/{close(f);f=""}'
```

Here is sample (not certificate)

**Input**

```
$ cat file
BEGIN
1
END

BEGIN
2
END

BEGIN
3
END
```

**Execution**

<s>`$ awk '/BEGIN/{f=i++".extracted.crt"}/BEGIN/,/END/{print > f;if(/END/)close(f)}' file`</s>

```
$ awk '/BEGIN/{f=(++i)".extracted.crt"} f{print>f} /END/{close(f);f=""}' file
```

**Output files**

```
$ ls *.crt
0.extracted.crt  1.extracted.crt  2.extracted.crt
```

**File contents of each**

```
$ for i in *.crt; do echo $i; cat $i; done
0.extracted.crt
BEGIN
1
END
1.extracted.crt
BEGIN
2
END
2.extracted.crt
BEGIN
3
END
```

Comment: looks like is not working, is displaying 
`awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1`

Comment: @JavierSalas which version of awk or else try `awk '/BEGIN/ {f=sprintf("%d.extracted.crt",i++)}/BEGIN/,/END/{print > f;if(/END/)close(f)}'`

Comment: @JavierSalas that error message means you are using old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris). Never use that awk. If you are on Solaris then use/install gawk and if that's not possible for some reason then use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead.

Comment: But nawk has fewer features than /usr/xpg4/bin/awk and is further from being POSIX compliant and so isn't worth mentioning IMHO since xpg4 is available and superior to nawk.

Comment: @JavierSalas instead of `awk` use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` and  rest of the things

Comment: @JavierSalas Then you are running the same tool - old, broken awk. Please read my earlier comment and just do what it says.

Comment: @EdMorton I did it as you suggested ;