# Use an array created using awk as a variable in another awk script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to use awk to extract data using a conditional statement containing an array created using another awk script.

The awk script I use for creating the array is as follows:

```
array=($(awk 'NR>1 { print $1 }' < file.tsv))
```

Then, to use this array in the other awk script

```
awk var="${array[@]}"  'FNR==1{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ heading[i]=$i } next } { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="1" && heading[i] in var){ close(outFile); outFile=heading[i]".txt"; print ">kmer"NR-1"\n"$1 >> (outFile) }}}' < input.txt
```

However, when I run this, the following error occurs.

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file 'foo' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

I've already looked at multiple posts on why this error occurs and on how to correctly [implement a shell variable in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script), but none of these have worked so far. However, when removing the shell variable and running the script it does work.

```
awk 'FNR==1{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ heading[i]=$i } next } { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="1"){ close(outFile); outFile=heading[i]".txt"; print ">kmer"NR-1"\n"$1 >> (outFile) }}}' < input.txt
```

I really need that conditional statement but don't know what I am doing wrong with implementing the bash variable in awk and would appreciate some help.

Thx in advance.

Comment: You can not pass an array to a child process. You can only pass individual strings.  This is a design restriction of Linux (and most, if not all, other operating systems), where the only kind of value which can be "understood" by all processes is a string. To simulate passing an array, you would have to first serialize it into a string and then deserialize it on the receiveing side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier and more efficient to process both files in a single `awk`:

<sub>**edit:** fixed issues in comment, thanks @EdMorton</sub>

```bash
awk '
    FNR == NR {
        if ( FNR > 1 )
            var[$1]
        next
    }
    FNR == 1 {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
            heading[i] = $i
        next
    }
    {
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
            if ( $i == "1" && heading[i] in var) {
                outFile = heading[i] ".txt"
                print ">kmer" (NR-1) "\n" $1 >> (outFile)
                close(outFile)
            }
    }
' file.tsv input.txt
```

Comment: You should do `close(outfile)` after the write rather than before it so you don't leave the loop having left the last output file open. I think that first block should probably be `FNR == NR { if ( FNR > 1 ) { var[$1] } next }` so the `next` isn't skipped for the first line of the first file but its hard to say without sample input/output.

Comment: @EdMorton my bad you’re right; I didn’t give it much thoughts when writing the first block. The rest is a copy paste of OP’s code; not sure that’s even worth to close the files

Comment: closing the files is worthwhile in case you hit the "too many open files" limit (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32878146/1745001 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45285560/1745001). I'm not really following the logic of the script (haven't thought about it much) so idk if that can become an issue or not for this script.

Comment: @EdMorton the number of output files is limited to `NF`, so it’s probably not so big to hit a limit

Comment: Depends if you're using the default awk on Solaris or not as [it's limit on concurrently open files is 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45285560/1745001). I don't usually consider that awks limitations (it is old, broken awk after all) but since closing files robustly is such a simple thing, no harm in doing it IMHO.

Comment: @Fravadona : to be fair to Ed, i just threw a `1.1 GB` mp4 into `mawk2`, and tell it to split fields byte-by-byte - and `NF` came out to be `NF = 1,140,275,285` - `1.14` ***billion***

Answer (score 2):

That specific error messages is because you forgot `-v` in front of `var=` (it should be `awk -v var=`, not just `awk var=`) but as others have pointed out, you can't set an array variable on the awk command line. Also note that `array` in your code is a **shell** array, not an **awk** array, and shell and awk are 2 completely different tools each with their own syntax, semantics, scopes, etc.

Here's how to really do what you're trying to do:

```
array=( "$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1 { print $1 }' < file.tsv)" )

awk -v xyz="${array[*]}" '
    BEGIN{ split(xyz,tmp,RS); for (i in tmp) var[tmp[i]] }
    ... now use `var` as you were trying to ...
'
```

For example:

```
$ cat file.tsv
col1    col2
a b     c d e
f g h   i j
```

```
$ cat -T file.tsv
col1^Icol2
a b^Ic d e
f g h^Ii j
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1 { print $1 }' < file.tsv
a b
f g h
```

```
$ array=( "$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1 { print $1 }' < file.tsv)" )
```

```
$ awk -v xyz="${array[*]}" '
    BEGIN {
        split(xyz,tmp,RS)
        for (i in tmp) {
            var[tmp[i]]
        }
        for (idx in var) {
            print "<" idx ">"
        }
    }
'
<f g h>
<a b>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might store string in variable, then use [`split` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to turn that into array, consider following simple example, let `file1.txt` content be

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

and `file2.txt` content be

```
1
3
2
```

then

```
var1=$(awk '{print $1}' file1.txt)
awk -v var1="$var1" 'BEGIN{split(var1,arr)}{print "First column value in line number",$1,"is",arr[$1]}' file2.txt
```

gives output

```
First column value in line number 1 is A
First column value in line number 3 is G
First column value in line number 2 is D
```

Explanation: I store output of 1st `awk` command, which is then used as 1st argument to `split` function in 2nd `awk` command. **Disclaimer**: this solutions assumes all files involved have delimiter compliant with default GNU `AWK` behavior, i.e. one-or-more whitespaces is always delimiter.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*