# grep or sed to match a block between start and end using same pattern

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with the following info:

```
start pattern1
line1
line2
...
end pattern1
line3
line4
start pattern2
...
```

my output should be:
`start pattern1
line1
line2
end pattern1`

If I know what `pattern1` is , I can do

```
sed '/start pattern1/,/end pattern1/p' <file>
```

but here, I want to match `pattern1` (like `\S+` in perl regex) and use the same (like `$1`) in the end. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the expected output, could you please mention that also in your post.

Comment: You still can use `sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern1/p' input` for your request

Comment: Could you give a real example? Are the words `start`  and `end` present? Or only `patern`?

Comment: Never use range expressions, always use a flag instead. That means you can't use sed of course - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/23934486/1745001 for how to print text between conditions.

Comment: to add clarification to my question: 'start' and 'end' are prefix keywords to an unknown `pattern1` that i would like to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) in Perl, patterns aren't tested at the same time

```
perl -wnE'print if /start ([A-Za-z0-9_:]+)/ ... /end $1/' intput.txt
```

*Updated to the actual pattern, specified in comments.*

I tested using captures (in a `do` block instead of just `print`) and it worked but problems may lie in wait if there are other captures.  If you *don't capture* anything in some other regex this works.

Note the use of `...` instead of `..`, to *not* test the right operand until the next evaluation.

Comment: I tried this as you have written it (without do) and it doesnt seem to work. It prints the whole file.

Comment: @user2623661  I just tried again (it was tested when I posted), copy-pasting the one-liner and running it on a file like your example, with lines added before and after.  It works.  What is your real input like?

Comment: @user2623661  Hang on ... I noticed your comment, that `pattern1` is "_unknown_" -- what do you mean by that? What kind of a thing is it?  Is it just anything that follows "start" (or your actual "_prefix keyword_"), or is there some rule to what it can be?

Comment: it is a 'word' meaning no space and has some special characters  [A-Za-z0-9_:]

Comment: @user2623661  Thanks, updated, works in my test.  I added multiple such sections to my test file, with other lines before, between, and after.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/pattern/,//p' file
```

This invokes a range which is a flip-flop match, the empty `//` matches the last regexp. The `p` prints everything while the range switch is true.

N.B. the `-n` invokes seds grep-like nature and turns off the automatic printing.

An alternative:

```
sed '/pattern/!d;:a;n;//!ba' file
```

Comment: +1. `//` is the sed magic here.  That said, it would break with any substitution or matching in the range.  You'd have to pipe sed to sed if you wanted that.

Comment: i am guessing this wont work with my case since i have a 'start' and 'end' prefix to 'pattern'

Answer (score 1):

Using awk to print between `pattern1`s (inclusive):

```
$ awk '/pattern1/{p=!p;print;next} p' file
pattern1
line1
line2
...
pattern1
```

The regex could be defined better, like `/^pattern1$/` or `$0=="pattern1"`.

Answer (score 0):

try following solution too with awk and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -v RS="" '{match($0,/start pattern1.*start pattern1/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

**EDIT:** OP haven't shown like Input_file could have empty lines too, as per CWLiu, I am adding a suggestion which will work in case of any empty lines too.

```
awk '/start pattern1/{print;getline;while($0 !~ /start pattern1/){print;getline};print}' Input_file
```

Comment: This doesn't work if empty lines are included between pattern1

Comment: @CWLiu: OP haven't mentioned that, not an issue. I have added one more solution to deal with empty lines also.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's an `awk` implementation based on an alternative interpretation of your question (since it's not quite clear).

If you want to detect the `pattern1` from the first line that starts with `start`, and then print every line until the `end pattern1`, you can do it like this:

```
$ awk '/^start / {pat=$2; next}  /^end / && $2~pat {exit}  {print}' file 
line1
line2
...
```