# Print specific lines from file

Tags: search, awk, sed, grep, cat

I have a text file like this:

```
OBJ O1 = {
{P11},
{0}
};

OBJ O2 = {
{P21},
{P22},
{P23},
{0}
};

OBJ O3 = {
{P31},
{P32},
{0}
};
```

I want to print only lines starting by `OBJ O2` and ending by first `{0}` after `OBJ O2`

```
OBJ O2 = {
{P21},
{P22},
{P23},
{0}
};
```

Is there a solution to print these lines using cat, sed, awk or grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
awk '/OBJ O2/,/^};$/' file
```

Comment: Or `awk '$2=="O2"' RS= input` or `awk '$1$2=="OBJO2"' RS= input`

Comment: `awk '/^OBJ O2/' RS= input`

Comment: Got it `The empty string "" (a string without any characters) has a special meaning as the value of RS. It means that records are separated by one or more blank lines and nothing else.` - works quite well on this case  !

Answer (score 0):

An awk alternative (without range expression), cf.
[Is a /start/,/end/ range expression ever useful in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23934486/8860865)

```
awk '/^OBJ O2/{f=1} f{print; if(/};/) f=0}' file
```