# How to skip lines between two patterns with awk?

Tags: awk

One line starting with \hello is skipped using

```
awk '/\\hello/{next}'
```

How to edit the command above to skip lines between \hello and \hello2?

input

```
text
\hello
text
hi
\hello2
text2
```

desired output:

```
text
text2
```

Comment: What if there's never a `\hello2` - should the text starting with `\hello` be printed or not. And there are no patterns - always state if you're talking about strings or regexps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its [not recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk), you can do the following:

```
$ awk '/^\\hello$/,/^\\hello2$/{next}1' file
```

The better, more adaptable way is:

```
$ awk '/^\\hello$/{f=1}(f==0){print};/^\\hello2$/{f=0}' file
```

which is reducible too:

```
$ awk '/^\\hello$/{f=1}!f;/^\\hello2$/{f=0}' file
```

or see Ed Morton's comment (see below)

Comment: Why would using the *regex range pattern* expression not be recommended? It is provided for in `man 1 awk`? (see `pattern1,pattern2` under the `"Patterns"` heading)  and is supported by both `gawk` and POSIX `awk`.

Comment: `[\\]` is just "\\"

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk

Comment: FWIW: `awk '$0=="\\hello"{f=1} !f; $0=="\\hello2"{f=0}' file`

Comment: @EdMorton - Thank You. That does add clarity to the pros and cons of the use of a range pattern. I have to admit, I have only considered range patterns for use with `sed` prior to this question, and went to the man pages to determine whether it was `gawk` limited or was POSIX as well. [man 1 gawk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html) and [man 1.p awk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html) I agree with the rational you posted as well as here, that the range pattern is better avoided -- learning has occurred -- it's been a good day.