# awk and flagging identical patterns

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm missing something about awk pattern matching a using flags --

Given a file:

```
2019 foo
 a
 b
 c
2019 bar
 d
 e
 f
2019 foobar
 g
 h
 i
```

I can use awk with flags and get the expected output --
`awk '/foo/{flag=1;next} /^[0-9]+/{flag=0} flag' file`

```
 a
 b
 c
 g
 h
 i
```

But if I exclude the next to include the matched pattern, then nothing is printed.
Does awk continue from the matched line?

Using another syntax --
`awk '/foo/,/2019/' file`

```
2019 foo
2019 foobar
```

I was expecting awk to print between and including the match.
I'm definitely missing something on syntax.

Comment: When you omit `next`, since the current line matches `^[0-9]+` flag is down before anything is printed. The range fails for the same reason as well

Comment: The straightforward way of printing the line matching `foo` is to `print` it before `next`.

Comment: for  `/foo/,/2019/`, note that the same line matches for both start and end pattern.  So you only get these two lines.  I guess your intention is `/2019 foo/,/2019 foobar/`

Comment: {flag=1;print;next} definitely works to print the match -- ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the range expression and then you don't have to try to understand them. A flag is always a better option anyway as it's clearer and easier to customize, see [Is a /start/,/end/ range expression ever useful in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23934486/1745001).

Your code using a flag should probably look like this though:

```
$ awk 'NF==2{found=0} found; $2 ~ /foo/{found=1}' file
 a
 b
 c
 g
 h
 i
```

or if you really like your original conditions:

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]/{found=0} found; /foo/{found=1}' file
 a
 b
 c
 g
 h
 i
```

Naming a flag variable `flag` is like naming a numeric variable `number` instead of whatever it really represents (total, average, etc.). Don't do that - name your flag variables based on what they represent about your data, in this case that you **found** the line matching your target regexp. When people abbreviate a flag variable to `f`, that's an abbreviation for `found`, not for `flag`.

Comment: Ty Ed, this is good information.

I was using `flag` because that's what I was setting -- a flag to mark a range.
But I agree, it makes an easier read to call it something relatable.

Using: 
`awk '/^[0-9]/{found=0} found; /foo/{found=1}'` 
I was wondering about the placement of the print statement.
As above, it only prints the range...

`awk '/^[0-9]/{found=0} /foo/{found=1} found'` 
But if it's moved to the end, then it also prints the match, which is what I was looking for, but still confuses the bejebus out of me.

Comment: In my case I also cannot use NF because the actual data being parsed may contain a changing number of columns.

Comment: If your real data doesn't follow the format shown in your question then you should fix your question. wrt being confused - you have `/^[0-9]/{f=0} /foo/{f=1} f{print}`. Just 3 separate condition/action blocks. The first 2 set/clear `f` and the 3rd one tests `f`. so when `f` is tested depends on where `f{print}` is located relative to the other 2 blocks and whether or not it's true depends on whether or not the conditions THEY are testing are true and so causing `f` to get set/cleared. Take a look at the examples in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001, maybe that'll help.