# Extracting all lines between and including 2 different delimiters when the second one is repeated

Tags: awk

Let's assume the following file:

```
delimiter_1
1
2
delimiter_22
blah
blah blah
delimiter_3
3
2
delimiter_2
```

The goal is to extract all lines between and including 'delimiter_3' and 'delimiter_2' to get:

```
delimiter_3
3
2
delimiter_2
```

This can be done with:

```
awk "/^delimiter_3$/{a=1};a;/^delimiter_2$/{exit}" file
```

However, if 'delimiter_2' is repeated such as:

```
delimiter_1
1
2
delimiter_2
blah
blah blah
delimiter_3
3
2
delimiter_2
```

the previous awk command returns an empty result.

Is this an issue with the command or awk?

---

P.S: I've noticed some other similarly worded questions, but AFAIK, none of them covers the exact same use-case.

EDIT: I've replaced all mentions of 'pattern' with 'delimiter'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a;/^pattern_2$/{exit}` should be `a;a&&/^pattern_2$/{exit}` or similar so the `pattern_2` comparison and subsequent `exit` only happens when `a` is true. The better general approach given non-nested, non-overlapping ranges is this to find all matches:

```
/start/{f=1} f{print; if (/end/) f=0}
```

or this to just find the first one:

```
/start/{f=1} f{print; if (/end/) exit}
```

Using the variable name `a` to indicate you **f**ound a match is less useful/obvious/clear than using `f` (also, `a` is often used for the name of an **a**rray).

Never use the word "pattern" when talking about matching text, btw, use regexp or string, whichever one you mean. See [How do I find the text that matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern).

And if you're ever tempted to use a range expression instead of a flag for this, I wouldn't - see [Is a /start/,/end/ range expression ever useful in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk).