# How to use AWK/GAWK to select/print records/lines between two dates of the format YYYY/MM/DD?

Tags: awk

I have a question related to the range option in gawk `BEGPAT, ENDPAT {ACTION}` , it seems unsuited to my case OR MORE LIKELY the problem is my misunderstanding of how range works.

I want to print/select the records/lines between a range of dates of the form YYYY-MM-DD. The dates are in a specific FIELD/Column, they are in ascending order, and they are not unique, ie:

```
2021-08-01
2021-08-02
2021-08-02
2021-08-02
2021-08-03
2021-08-04
2021-08-05
2021-08-05
2021-08-05
```

How can I select lets say, from 2021-08-02 to 2021-08-05, the actual data goes back two years, to get:

```
2021-08-02
2021-08-02
2021-08-02
2021-08-03
2021-08-04
2021-08-05
2021-08-05
2021-08-05
```

I tried the following:
`'/2021-08-03/, /2021-08-05/{print}'`

Resulting in this:

```
2021-08-03
2021-08-04
2021-08-05
```

Any help within the scope of gawk/awk is appreciated. The documentation about ranges is  [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html), but since I'm just trying to learn to code it can difficult to understand sometimes. Perhaps there are other approaches **within awk** to solve this?

Comment: Range expressions are most useful with `sed`. `awk` allows the use of variables, so a simple state variable used as a flag is often the best approach.

Comment: For what reason do you use `/2021-08-03/` as your starting date instead of the one you really want (`/2021-08-02/`)?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v beg='2021-08-02' -v end='2021-08-05' '
    $1 >= beg { inRange=1 }
    $1 > end { exit }
    inRange { print }
' file
```

Unless you're coding strictly for brevity, range expressions are never the best approach and you should always use a flag variable (which I named `inRange` above but `f` or `found` or whatever other name you like is fine too) instead, see [Is a /start/,/end/ range expression ever useful in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk).

If you prefer a briefer solution you can do the above with hard-coded values and a shorter variable name as:

```
awk '$1=="2021-08-02"{f=1} $1>"2021-08-05"{exit} f' file
```

Note that, among other things, the above is more efficient than using a range expression as it'll exit after the range is printed rather than continuing reading the rest of the input.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is *unsuited to my case* as you have repeats

```
2021-08-01
2021-08-02
2021-08-02
2021-08-02
2021-08-03
2021-08-04
2021-08-05
2021-08-05
2021-08-05
```

so `ENDPAT` will trigger at first occurence of `2021-08-05`. If you must use range AT ANY PRICE then you might use GNU `AWK` as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
2021-08-01
2021-08-02
2021-08-02
2021-08-02
2021-08-03
2021-08-04
2021-08-05
2021-08-05
2021-08-05
```

then

```
awk '/2021-08-0[25]/,/2021-08-05/{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
2021-08-02
2021-08-02
2021-08-02
2021-08-03
2021-08-04
2021-08-05
2021-08-05
2021-08-05
```

Explanation: there are 2 ranges in 1: one from `2021-08-02` to `2021-08-05` and second from `2021-08-05` to `2021-08-05`.
EDIT: If composing regular expression this way is not possible you might use `|` i.e. `awk '/2021-08-02|2021-08-05/,/2021-08-05/' file.txt` as suggested in comment

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: In this case `awk '/2021-08-0[2-5]/' file.txt` would work the same. But there are limitations: what if the starting and ending dates differ by more than one character? I suggest to improve your answer with a more generic solution: `awk '/2021-08-02|2021-08-05/,/2021-08-05/' file.txt`.

Comment: That would match anywhere in each line of input but the OP said the dates they are interested in only exist in 1 column of the input so it should really be `awk '$1~/2021-08-0[25]/,$1~/2021-08-05/{print}' file.txt`, etc. (if the date is in $1).