# Bash print all line except start to end pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this input file with list of player names.

```
Cristiano Ronaldo
Anthony Martial
Jadon Sancho
Marcus Rashford
Bruno Fernandes
Fred
Scott McTominay
Donny Van De Beek
# Start U23 Team
Alvaro Fernandez
Zidane Iqbal
Facundo Pellistri
Hannibal Mejbri
Charlie Savage
# End U23 Team
Harry Maguire
Lisandro Martinez
Alex Telles
```

I want to exclude line starting with `Start U23 Team` and end with `End U23 Team`, so the end result will be:

```
Cristiano Ronaldo
Anthony Martial
Jadon Sancho
Marcus Rashford
Bruno Fernandes
Fred
Scott McTominay
Donny Van De Beek
Harry Maguire
Lisandro Martinez
Alex Telles
```

I can print the U23 Player with this command `awk "/# End U23 Team/{f=0} f; /# Start U23 Team/{f=1}" file`, but how to do vice versa ?

Comment: Don't use a range expression, use a flag as that lets you control whatever you want to print from a range - see [is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `d` command in `sed` to exclude lines.

```
sed '/# Start U23 Team/,/# End U23 Team/d' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk "/# Start U23 Team/ {f=1} !f {print} /# End U23 Team/ {f=0}" file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -z 's/# Start.*# End U23 Team\n//' input_file
Cristiano Ronaldo
Anthony Martial
Jadon Sancho
Marcus Rashford
Bruno Fernandes
Fred
Scott McTominay
Donny Van De Beek
Harry Maguire
Lisandro Martinez
Alex Telles
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk`, please try following code, written and tested with shown samples only. Simply making use of `RS` variable where setting it to regex `'(^|\n)# Start U23 Team\n.*\n# End U23 Team\n` as per requirement and then in main program simply printing the lines.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)# Start U23 Team\n.*\n# End U23 Team\n' '{sub(/\n$/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/# Start U23 Team/,/# End U23 Team/{next}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can print the U23 Player with this command `awk "/# End U23 Team/{f=0} f; /# Start U23 Team/{f=1}" file`, but how to do vice versa
> ?

This code might be reworked following way

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=1} /# Start U23 Team/{f=0} f; /# End U23 Team/{f=1}' file
```

Explanation: `BEGIN` pattern allows executing action before starting processing lines, here I set `f` value to `1`, `/# Start U23 Team/` was swapped with `/# End U23 Team/`