# When the search string is found, then start printing; stop printing when the character '}' is found at the beginning of a line

Tags: awk

How to get the desired output?
For a text file, when the search string "import " is found, then start printing; stop printing when the character '}' is found at the beginning of a line.
e.g.
input:

```
} 2.4.1. Display Name Generators JUnit Jupiter supports custom display name generators that can be configured via the @DisplayNameGeneration annotation. Values provided via @DisplayName annotations always take precedence over display names generated by a DisplayNameGenerator. Generators can be created by implementing DisplayNameGenerator. Here are some default ones available in Jupiter: DisplayNameGenerator Behavior Standard Matches the standard display name generation behavior in place since JUnit Jupiter 5.0 was released. Simple Removes trailing parentheses for methods with no parameters. ReplaceUnderscores Replaces underscores with spaces. IndicativeSentences Generates complete sentences by concatenating the names of the test and the enclosing classes. Note that for IndicativeSentences, you can customize the separator and the underlying generator by using @IndicativeSentencesGeneration as shown in the following example. import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGeneration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGenerator;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.IndicativeSentencesGeneration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;

class DisplayNameGeneratorDemo {

    @Nested
    @DisplayNameGeneration(DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores.class)
    class A_year_is_not_supported {

        @Test
        void if_it_is_zero() {
        }

        @DisplayName("A negative value for year is not supported by the leap year computation.")
        @ParameterizedTest(name = "For example, year {0} is not supported.")
        @ValueSource(ints = { -1, -4 })
        void if_it_is_negative(int year) {
        }

    }

    @Nested
    @IndicativeSentencesGeneration(separator = " -> ", generator = ReplaceUnderscores.class)
    class A_year_is_a_leap_year {

        @Test
        void if_it_is_divisible_by_4_but_not_by_100() {
        }

        @ParameterizedTest(name = "Year {0} is a leap year.")
        @ValueSource(ints = { 2016, 2020, 2048 })
        void if_it_is_one_of_the_following_years(int year) {
        }

    }

} +-- DisplayNameGeneratorDemo [OK]
  +-- A year is not supported [OK]
  | +-- A negative value for year is not supported by the leap year computation. [OK]
  | | +-- For example, year -1 is not supported. [OK]
  | | '-- For example, year -4 is not supported. [OK]
  | '-- if it is zero() [OK]
```

output:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGeneration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGenerator;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.IndicativeSentencesGeneration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;

class DisplayNameGeneratorDemo {

    @Nested
    @DisplayNameGeneration(DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores.class)
    class A_year_is_not_supported {

        @Test
        void if_it_is_zero() {
        }

        @DisplayName("A negative value for year is not supported by the leap year computation.")
        @ParameterizedTest(name = "For example, year {0} is not supported.")
        @ValueSource(ints = { -1, -4 })
        void if_it_is_negative(int year) {
        }

    }

    @Nested
    @IndicativeSentencesGeneration(separator = " -> ", generator = ReplaceUnderscores.class)
    class A_year_is_a_leap_year {

        @Test
        void if_it_is_divisible_by_4_but_not_by_100() {
        }

        @ParameterizedTest(name = "Year {0} is a leap year.")
        @ValueSource(ints = { 2016, 2020, 2048 })
        void if_it_is_one_of_the_following_years(int year) {
        }

    }

}
```

I tried:

```
awk '/^} / { matchstr = 0 } {if ($0 ~ / import org/ || $0 ~ /^import org/) matchstr = 1 } matchstr { print }' input
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    !f && match($0,/(^| )import org\./) { $0=substr($0,RSTART); sub(/^ /,""); f=1 }
    f { if ( sub(/^}.*/,"}") ) f=0; print }
' file
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGeneration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGenerator;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.IndicativeSentencesGeneration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;

class DisplayNameGeneratorDemo {

    @Nested
    @DisplayNameGeneration(DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores.class)
    class A_year_is_not_supported {

        @Test
        void if_it_is_zero() {
        }

        @DisplayName("A negative value for year is not supported by the leap year computation.")
        @ParameterizedTest(name = "For example, year {0} is not supported.")
        @ValueSource(ints = { -1, -4 })
        void if_it_is_negative(int year) {
        }

    }

    @Nested
    @IndicativeSentencesGeneration(separator = " -> ", generator = ReplaceUnderscores.class)
    class A_year_is_a_leap_year {

        @Test
        void if_it_is_divisible_by_4_but_not_by_100() {
        }

        @ParameterizedTest(name = "Year {0} is a leap year.")
        @ValueSource(ints = { 2016, 2020, 2048 })
        void if_it_is_one_of_the_following_years(int year) {
        }

    }

}
```

If you have GNU awk you could change `match($0,/(^| )import org\./)` to `match($0,/\<import org\>/)` and remove the associated `sub()`.

See [Is a /start/,/end/ range expression ever useful in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23934486/1745001) for my opinion of why you should always use a flag variable instead of a range expression.

Answer (score 1):

Would this suit your use-case?

```
awk '/^import/,/^}/ {gsub("^} .*", "}", $0); print}' input
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGeneration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGenerator;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.IndicativeSentencesGeneration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;

class DisplayNameGeneratorDemo {

    @Nested
    @DisplayNameGeneration(DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores.class)
    class A_year_is_not_supported {

        @Test
        void if_it_is_zero() {
        }

        @DisplayName("A negative value for year is not supported by the leap year computation.")
        @ParameterizedTest(name = "For example, year {0}
        @ValueSource(ints = { -1, -4 })
        void if_it_is_negative(int year) {
        }

    }

    @Nested
    @IndicativeSentencesGeneration(separator = " -> ", generator = ReplaceUnderscores.class)
    class A_year_is_a_leap_year {

        @Test
        void if_it_is_divisible_by_4_but_not_by_100() {
        }

        @ParameterizedTest(name = "Year {0}
        @ValueSource(ints = { 2016, 2020, 2048 })
        void if_it_is_one_of_the_following_years(int year) {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @ jared_mamrot Do you use the range pattern as described at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html ?

Comment: Both @ Ed Morton and  @ jared_mamrot scripts are good but miss the first line of the output:
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;

Comment: @albertkao9 that's why you should post **minimal** sample input/output that demonstrates your needs, because otherwise, e.g. given an example that requires scroll bars to read, it's hard for us to notice things like a missing line in the output. I updated my answer to handle that now.

Comment: Sorry for the oversight/error in my approach albertkao9; obviously @EdMorton's answer is the best approach. Glad you solved your problem :)