# Print lines between 1st match and 2nd match, 2nd match that came after the 1st match in Linux

Tags: shell, perl, awk, pattern-matching

I have a series of data I want to print the data after one match and next different match which comes after the first match for example,

I have

```
AAA 
AAAD
BBB 
CCC
AAA
AAADD
```

Want the data between AAAD and AAA.

There's AAA in the 1st line too but I want it to catch AAAD first and then print the data till it catches the next match which is AAA on line 5

output needed :

```
AAAD
BBB
CCC
AAA
```

I tried

perl -lne 'print if /AAAD/../AAA/' p

it gave

```
AAAD
AAADD
```

it's giving exact matches and printing them rather than giving lines in between.

Comment: Use `^` and `$` to match the beginning and the end of a line, e.g. `perl -lne 'print if /^AAAD$/../^AAA$/'` or `awk '/^AAAD$/,/^AAA$/'` or `sed -n '/^AAAD$/,/^AAA$/p'`.

Comment: You need to use the three dot operator: `...` to prevent the rhs to match on the same line.

Comment: What if `AAAD` exists but `AAA` doesn't - print from `AAAD` to the end of the file or not print anything? What if there are 2 `AAAD` lines before the first `AAA` line - print from the first `AAAD` line or from the second? What if there are 2 `AAA` lines after a `AAAD` line - print til the first `AAA` line or the second? What if there are nested `AAAD -> AAA` blocks? Please [edit] your question to tell us these and all other "rainy day" requirements you can think of or you're likely to get a solution that only works for sunny day scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, you need to use [the `...` range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Range-Operators) to prevent matching on the same line. Like so:

```
C:\perl>perl -lnwe "print if /AAAD/../AAA/" a.txt
AAAD
AAADD

C:\perl>perl -lnwe "print if /AAAD/.../AAA/" a.txt
AAAD
BBB
CCC
AAA
AAADD
```

From the documentation:

> If you don't want it to test the right operand until the next evaluation, as in sed, just use three dots ("...") instead of two. In all other regards, "..." behaves just like ".." does.

This code, with the regexes you provided, allows partial matches. If this is not what you want, you can use anchors to enforce only complete matches. E.g.:

```
C:\perl>perl -lnwe "print if /^AAAD$/.../^AAA$/" a.txt
AAAD
BBB
CCC
AAA
```

Comment: OP doesn't want the last `AAADD` be included, as it's past the final `AAA` line. Also, this would still start the range with lines **containing** the start pattern, i.e. if `AAAD` was preceded by, say, `AAADA`, the range would begin there.

Comment: @pmf Yes. And the OP has not mentioned either of those things as unwanted. The last line is the start of a new block, with a partial match. I suppose I could mention anchors to prevent this

Answer (score 2):

This will work for the one sunny-day scenario you describe:

```
$ awk '$0=="AAAD"{f=1} f; $0=="AAA"{f=0}' file
AAAD
BBB
CCC
AAA
```

but, just like any other answer you get at this point, it may not be the right solution for you depending on your requirements for rainy day scenarios, including some I listed in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78059830/print-lines-between-1st-match-and-2nd-match-2nd-match-that-came-after-the-1st-m#comment137615143_78059830).

I'm using literal string instead of regexp matching so it works even if your matching strings contain regexp metachars. See [How do I find the text that matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more info.

Though awk supports range expression such as `/^AAAD$/,/^AAA$/` or `$0=="AAAD",$0=="AAA"` I used a flag `f` instead because range expressions require a total rewrite or duplicate code if you want to do anything even slightly different with your script in future, e.g. not print the start and/or end line of the matching block or not print from the line that matches the starting pattern to the end of the file if the ending pattern is not matched. See [Is a /start/,/end/ range expression ever useful in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
perl -ne'print if /^AAAD$/ .. /^AAA$/'
```

Or if you just want the first:

```bash
perl -ne'print if $x ||= /^AAAD$/; exit if $x && /^AAA$/;'
```

---

This was your attempt:

```bash
perl -ne'print if /AAAD/ .. /AAA/'
```

It's close. The issue is that the string `AAAD` matches `/AAA/`. We can fix that using anchors

```bash
perl -ne'print if /^AAAD$/ .. /^AAA$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/^AAAD$/,/^AAA$/' file

AAAD
BBB
CCC
AAA
```

same with `sed`

```
$ sed -n '/^AAAD$/,/^AAA$/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^AAAD$/{:a;N;/^AAA$/M!ba;p}' file
```

This is a filter operation so employ the `-n` option to prevent implicit printing.

Match on a line only containing `AAAD` and then gather up future lines until one containing only `AAA`.

Print the collection and repeat.

All other lines will quietly disappear.

N.B. The range operation behaves in a flip-flop manner and is not suitable if both start and end conditions must be met i.e. if a line containing only `AAAD` is matched any command following the range will be activated until a line containing only `AAA` or the **end of the file**.