# Command sed context addressing not working as expected

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file `file.txt` with the content:

```
lord
blue
bird
The sky
reptile
lorwood
wood
```

I'm trying to print the lines between "lord" and "reptile" using command `sed` and Basic Regular Expression as:

```bash
$ sed -n '/^lor/,/^rep/p' file.txt
```

However, it prints the whole file, like a `cat`. Why?

The version of `sed` I'm using is:

```bash
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.8
Packaged by Debian
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jay Fenlason, Tom Lord, Ken Pizzini,
Paolo Bonzini, Jim Meyering, and Assaf Gordon.

This sed program was built with SELinux support.
SELinux is disabled on this system.

GNU sed home page: <https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <https://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a second `lor` line immediately after the `rep` line so sed is printing from `lord` to `reptile` and then from `lorwood` til the end of the file as 2 separate blocks which together encompass all of the lines from your input.

You can see the 2 separate blocks if you use awk and a flag instead of sed and a range expression:

```
$ awk '/^lor/{ print "{"; f=1 } f{ print; if (/^rep/) { print "}"; f=0 } } END{if (f) print "}"}' file.txt
{
lord
blue
bird
The sky
reptile
}
{
lorwood
wood
}
```

or, if you prefer:

```
$ awk '/^lor/{ ++blockNr; lineNr=1 } lineNr{ print "block="blockNr, "line="lineNr++, $0; if (/^rep/) lineNr=0 }' file.txt
block=1 line=1 lord
block=1 line=2 blue
block=1 line=3 bird
block=1 line=4 The sky
block=1 line=5 reptile
block=2 line=1 lorwood
block=2 line=2 wood
```

FWIW, I wouldn't use a range expression `/start/,/end/` (and so wouldn't use `sed`) for this as it's too hard to control the output, I'd use `awk` and a flag instead, see [Is a /start/,/end/ range expression ever useful in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk).

Comment: so, is it because, first, `sed` is selecting and applying the action to all the possible ranges that match my instruction, and secondly, because once a range starts with a /start/ pattern, it will extend till the end of the file if no match is found for the /end/ pattern?

Comment: @gambarimas87 correct on both counts. If that's not what you want then the clearest, simplest, most portable thing to do is switch to awk and use a flag.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/lor/{:a;N;/rep/!ba;p}' file
```

This is essentially a filter operation so use the `-n` command line option to suppress the implicit printing of each line.

Match `lor` and using a loop, gather up future lines until the collection contains `rep`, then print the collection and repeat.

N.B. Only a valid collection will be printed out by the `p` command, once the loop is ended.

Comment: Wow, I never thought you could do such things like looping with sed. Now I see why some people talk about sed "scripts", not just sed "commands". Thanks!